# App Pool User Unable to Execute Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, database-permissions

**Background**

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2's full text search to retrieve a number of documents, and wish to use the results of `sys.dm_fts_parser` to highlight the matching terms.

Doing that ordinarily requires permissions an app user should not have.  There is a solution [proposed on MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/transactsql/thread/a3ec4602-e0be-48f5-92ad-2eb25a6befc5) as well as a [deleted question/answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3816023/sys-dm-fts-parser-permission) (see [why it was deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65954/a-user-is-taking-questions-from-msdn-forums-asking-them-on-so-and-posting-the)).

**Problem**

I'm trying to implement the solution, but am unable to grant *execute* permission to the IIS App Pool user.

**What I have tried**

In SSMS under Security / Logins I created a user `IIS APPPOOL\My App`.  I grant that user `db_datareader` and `db_datawriter` for table access, and that works fine.

Again in SSMS:

- Under MyDB / Programmability / Stored Procedures I right-click on `dbo.usp_fts_parser`
- Select Properties, Permissions.
- Click Search...
- Add `IIS APPPOOL\My App`
- On the Explicit tab, Execute row I check Grant
- Click OK

**Question**

Why is this grant insufficient to execute `dbo.usp_fts_parser`?

**Notes**

- I can execute it just fine from SSMS logged in as an administrator.
- If I temporarily grant the sysadmin Server Role to `IIS APPPOOL\My App`, the code is able to execute `dbo.usp_fts_parser`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer originally posted at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3816023/sys-dm-fts-parser-permission/3816407#3816407:

In your database:

```
create procedure usp_fts_parser
    @query nvarchar(max)
with execute as caller
as
select * from sys.dm_fts_parser(@query, 1033, 0, 0);
go

grant execute on usp_fts_parser to [<some low priviledged user>]
go

create certificate sign_fts_parser
    encryption by password = 'Password#1234'
    with subject = 'sign_fts_parser';
go

add signature to object::usp_fts_parser
by certificate sign_fts_parser with password = 'Password#1234';
go

alter certificate sign_fts_parser
remove private key;
go

backup certificate sign_fts_parser
to file = 'c:\temp\sign_fts_parser.cer';
go
```

In master:

```
create certificate sign_fts_parser
from file = 'c:\temp\sign_fts_parser.cer';
go  

create login login_sign_fts_parser
from certificate sign_fts_parser;
go

grant control server to login_sign_fts_parser;
go
```

I just tested these steps on a SQL Server 2008 and I was able to execute the `usp_fts_parser` from a low privileged login. The only difference from the original post answer is that I added explicit GRANT EXECUTE on the stored procedure and I removed the unrequited enabling trustworthy step. In your case the `<low priviledged user>` should be `IIS APPPOOL\My App`, assuming you do *not* use impersonation in your ASP application.

The required permissions on calling `sys.dm_fts_parser` are being derived from the signature on the procedure which, via the certificate exported and imported into `master` database, has explicit CONTROL SERVER permission (highest possible priviledge). Because the private key of the certificate was explicitly removed there is no way to abuse the high priviledge associated with this certificate, since it cannot ever sign again anything (the private key is lost forever). See [Module Signing (Database Engine)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345102(v=sql.105).aspx) for more details.

Note that the steps above have to be repeated *every time you modify the stored procedure*. Any ALTER on the procedure will result in an automated, silent, drop of the associated signature. Loosing the module signature implies loosing the priviledges derived from this signature and thus the subsequent calls to `sys.dm_fts_parser` will fail for a low priviledged user.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I think the problem for me may have been *repeated every time you modify the stored procedure*.  I think I did edit the usp to return only a single column after following the outlined steps.  +1, and will test later today.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at official [MSDN help for this system function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280463%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) then you will find that it actually requires,

> **Permissions**
>
> Requires membership in the sysadmin fixed server role and access
>   rights to the specified stoplist.

So like says, that user have to be member of sysadmin fixed server role. I don't think there is any workaround for that.

Comment: The link I reference offers a work around. Since the SO version was posted by a high rep user and received 8 up votes I assume it can work.

Comment: That post is removed and probably that's why I didn't see solution. But after reading whole MSDN post it looks like that I was wrong, solution does exist. But I don't understand if solution does exist then why the question ? If issue is "why SYSADMIN role" then there was already request on MSFT CONNECT (which is now closed without fix which means MSFT is not going to fix this issue)

Comment: I think you need 10K rep to see the deleted SO post which is why I included the MSDN one.  I tried implementing the solution but still get the same error.  The premise of the solution is that the web user that does not have the SYSADMIN role can call a sproc that impersonates a user that does have the SYSADMIN role, but I cannot get that working.  Must be missing a key step.